# Dynamically change row background color using Tabulator

Tags: tabulator

I have this row formatter:

```
rowFormatter:function(row){
    if (Math.abs(row.getData().diff > 75))
    {
        row.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
```

It works perfectly! But my data is dynamically updated, and row background color should be changed to default if condition is not true. Something like:

```
rowFormatter:function(row){
        if (Math.abs(row.getData().diff > 75))
          {
            row.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
          }
        else { ... reset to default color... }
```

How to do it?

Comment: Possible, the solution is row.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "";